# Qt 5.3 and Win SDK 7.1: Cannot open include file ammintrin.h

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, qt, winapi, qt5

I installed Windows SDK 7.1 and Qt 5.3 using following steps:

1. Install Windows SDK 7.1 
   http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=8279
2. Install Visual C++ 2010 SP1 Compiler Update for the Windows SDK 7.1 
   http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=4422
3. Install Qt 5.3.0 for Windows 32-bit (VS 2010, OpenGL, 593 MB) 
   http://download.qt-project.org/official_releases/qt/5.3/5.3.0/qt-opensource-windows-x86-msvc2010_opengl-5.3.0.exe

I can see Qt Creator recognized installed compiler and debugger:
[image]

But, when I try to build even simple empty Qt Console application, i get:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\intrin.h:26: 
error: C1083: Cannot open include file: 'ammintrin.h': No such file or directory
```

Is it possible to set it up without installing Visual Studio ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a workaround with installing free Visual Studio 2013 for Windows Desktop Express.

Just follow these steps:

1. Install VS Express 2013 for Windows Desktop
2. Qt Online Installer for Windows (14 MB) (Info)
   http://download.qt-project.org/official_releases/online_installers/qt-opensource-windows-x86-1.6.0-3-online.exe. Install only qt.53.win32_msvc2013, there is no need for other platforms.
3. Standalone Debugging Tools for Windows (WinDbg)
   Install only debugging tools

Answer (score 0):

This is a known bug for some distributions of Visual C++, introduced by a security update.

Source : https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/660584

You need to avoid some Visual C++ distributions which were not updated since. The Windows SDK is one of them. Try with Visual Studio (expensive) or Visual Studio Express (free but several limitations)

Comment: Cool : downvoting without giving a comment. That's lame

Comment: In fact [here is MS admitting that a security update broke it, but refusing to fix it](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/660584/windows-update-kb2455033-breaks-build-with-missing-ammintrin-h)